# How to combine squareup developer account with merchant account

Tags: square-connect, square

For an integration we have created Squareup developer account and merchant account (with separate user details). Can we merge those two and use it as a single account?
When we create an account, is it already in production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to merge two separate accounts.